# How to center text label in iPhone Settings application

Tags: iphone, settings

When you look at **Settings - General - Keyboard** you can see text *"Double tapping the space bar will insert a period followed by a space".*

**Question:** how can I do something similar in my own app settings?

Got pretty close by using **PSGroupSpecifier** for text, but can't figure out how to center the text. Centering is the missing feature I'm now looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that with AppStore Settings bundles.

You can fake centering by inserting a lot of spaces at the beginning.

(Centering the text is restricted to internal "preference bundles".)

Comment: Ohh, no! Well, will add a few spaces I guess. Can fix it later, when have iPad to check how it looks in that layout. Wish I could make feature reqs for SDK...

Answer (score 0):

changed for ios 4.0 - > make use for the footerText field of a group specifier.

follow:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSGroupSpecifier.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007009-SW1

all you will need is in there.